# autocompletion send data id

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire

I have a response in the form of JSON

```
[
      {
          "id_ser_reg": "103",
          "n_ser_reg": "Operation NOC"
      },
      {
          "id_ser_reg": "120",
          "n_ser_reg": "Freelance"
      }
]
```

I have a searchtextfield and display "n_ser_reg" for title, but if I choose "n_ser_reg" I want to get the "id_ser_reg" too, I have try alamofire for get the response, but I don't know how to get "n_ser_reg" with "id_ser_reg" at the same time.

[image]

this is image for getting n_ser_reg, and i want if i click the button "cari" id_ser_reg i send, not n_ser_reg

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have a link, in that link ID_ser_reg is needed, but in UI it must display n_ser_reg, so I have to display n_ser_reg, and when the button is pressed, id_ser_reg that is owned by n_ser_reg is sent to the link

Comment: So are you saying that names and hrids doesn't produce the expected values from the dictionary?

Comment: You can use `Codable` to parse your JSON response.

Comment: no, I mean how can I choose a names but also take the hrid value, 
for example, I select NOC and I also get id 103. now I can only get id 103 if I select id 103

Comment: can you give me an example of Codable

Comment: What is the value if data that you're getting. Also, paste the code instead of adding  an image.

Comment: i have update my question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the response into a `dictionary`, you must create a `class/struct` and parse your data into it.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var id_ser_reg: String?
    var n_ser_reg: String?
}
```

The above struct conforms to `Codable protocol`, i.e. you can use its `properties` to parse directly to and from `JSON` response.

```
   if let data = response.data {
        let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
        print(response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `codable` to serialize data and keep array of dictionaries rather than adding two different array of name and id.

I added the data in an array :

```
let tempArray : [[String:Any]] = [["id_ser_reg":"103",
                                   "n_ser_reg":"Operation NOC",
                                   ],
                                  ["id_ser_reg":"120",
                                   "n_ser_reg":"Freelance",
    ]
]
```

and created a jsonData to to use `codable`:

```
do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tempArray, options: .prettyPrinted)

        print(jsonData)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

For `Codable` first create a `struct` :

```
struct JsonResponse: Codable {
    var id_ser_reg : String?
    var n_ser_reg : String?
}
```

and to serialize :

```
do {    
        let serverResponseData = try JSONDecoder().decode([JsonResponse].self, from: jsonData)

        print(serverResponseData[0].id_ser_reg!)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
}
```

as you can see the `serverResponseData` is an array now having name and id at each index. `Codable` will decrease your line of code of adding data one by one to an array.

**Edit**

If you want to go with what you have done. You can do one more thing.

Create an array as:

```
var arrayData = [[String:Any]]()
```

and in your response :

```
if let dictionaryArray = data as? [[String:Any]] {
    self.arrayData = dictionaryArray
}
```

Now you have an array of dictionaries which you can use whenever you want the data as:

```
let singleData = self.arrayData[0] as! [String:Any]
print(singleData["id_ser_reg"])
print(singleData["n_ser_reg"])
```

The image that you have added in the question doesn't explain that what is the exact UI and how you are using the data to populate in the UI. If possible add the exact code not the image of the code and add the logic of data integration with the UI in the question.
Hope that my answer helps you to achieve what you are trying.

Comment: is there a solution other than using codable ?

Comment: Do you have contacts that I can contact?